# SQL Server date/time overlapping check for event scheduling

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a event table that has the following columns:

```
StartDate datetime
EndDate datetime
StartTime nvarchar(10)
EndTime nvarchar(10)
```

Let's say a record has these values in the table:

```
StartDate: 2011-12-22 00:00:00.000
EndDate: 2011-12-22 00:00:00.000
StartTime: 4:00 PM
EndTime: 5:00 PM
```

Now, if someone comes to schedule an event, I need to make sure he can't schedule it for the same time or between the start and end times of this existing event.

So, he can schedule from 5:00 PM to 6:00 PM or from 11:00 AM to 4:00 PM but not 11:00 AM to 5:00 PM or 4:30 PM to 5:00 PM.

How can I check for this?  I know this isn't the best design for this table, but I have to stick to this design, else we will have to change a lot of middle layer and client side code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
declare @apptDate DATETIME

SET @apptDate = '12/22/2011 4:30PM'
select COUNT(*) 
from t1
where @apptDate Between
CAST( StartDate+StartTime as DateTime) and CAST( EndDate+EndTime as DateTime)  

SET @apptDate = '12/22/2011 6:30PM'
select COUNT(*) 
from t1
where @apptDate Between
CAST( StartDate+StartTime as DateTime) and CAST( EndDate+EndTime as DateTime)
```

If count(*) > 0, an appointment exists.   If not, the spot is free

Comment: You need also test the complete coverage

Answer (score 3):

When adding new record or modifying existing you chould check that your start or end timestamps not falling inside already existing time ranges and new range does not cover the existing.

Assuming that date also matters, not only time, then better way to store begin and end dates and times as DATETIME columns, for example StartDT and EndDT - in this case you have to check non-overlapping other rows with this statement

```
Where not exists(
    select * from yourtable 
    where (@newstart >= StartDT AND @newstart < EndDT) 
    OR (@newend > StartDT AND @newend <= EndDT) 
    OR (@newstart <= StartDT AND @newend >= EndDT)
)
```

Of course you can rewrite it as EXISTS clause instead of NON EXISTS

So, if you cannot change the schema, you should simply change StartDT and EndDT to the expressions, which compose corresponding values from the underlying string columns, for example

```
 StartDT = SUBSTRING(StartDate, 1, 10) + ' '+ StartTime
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to post my query here - might help someone.  Works like a charm.  Thanks for the help!

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PS_Event_Insert]
(
@UserID int,
@AmenityID int,
@DateFrom datetime,
@DateTo datetime,
@TimeFrom nvarchar(50),
@TimeTo nvarchar(50),
@Description nvarchar(max),
@IsPrivate bit,
@NumberOfPeople nvarchar(100),
@Food bit,
@StatusID int,
@Notes nvarchar(500) = NULL,
@EventID int OUTPUT
)
AS
declare @newdtfrom datetime = cast(@DateFrom + ' ' + @TimeFrom as datetime)
declare @newdtto datetime = cast(@DateTo + ' ' + @TimeTo as datetime)

DECLARE @RecCount int

BEGIN

SET @RecCount = (
select count(*) from [events]   
where (@newdtfrom >= cast([datefrom] + ' ' + [timefrom] as datetime) and @newdtfrom   <= cast([dateto] + ' ' + [timeto] as datetime))
or (@newdtto > cast([datefrom] + ' ' + [timefrom] as datetime) and @newdtto <=   cast([dateto] + ' ' + [timeto] as datetime))
or (@newdtfrom <= cast([datefrom] + ' ' + [timefrom] as datetime) and @newdtto >= cast([dateto] + ' ' + [timeto] as datetime))  
AND
[AmenityID] = @AmenityID
AND 
[StatusID] = 5
)

IF (@RecCount = 0)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [Events]
    (
        [UserID],
        [AmenityID],
        [DateFrom],
        [DateTo],
        [TimeFrom],
        [TimeTo],   
        [Description],
        [IsPrivate],
        [NumberOfPeople],
        [Food],
        [StatusID],
        [Notes]
    )
    VALUES
    (
        @UserID,
        @AmenityID,
        @DateFrom,
        @DateTo,
        @TimeFrom,
        @TimeTo,
        @Description,
        @IsPrivate,
        @NumberOfPeople,
        @Food,
        @StatusID,
        @Notes
    )

SET @EventID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SET @EventID = -999
END
END
```